# How to write multiple row data with a same column name in xml?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, xml-parsing, computer-vision, object-detection

In a panda dataframe I have multiple rows with a common column name. Now, I want to write those data with the same column name in an XML file. How I can archive that. Currently, my code, convert all row to separate  XML file ,with an attribute 'filename' as xml file name.Problem is that it replace all previous file with same name. Here is my major code, give me a solution, please.

```
 fields = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
```

.....

```
for i in range(num_of_images):

height = df['height'].iloc[i]
width = df['width'].iloc[i]
depth = 3
print(df.iloc[df['filename'] == fileName])
```

....

```
output_file = open( savedir+fileName + ".xml", 'w',encoding='utf8' )
```

Comment: change `'w'` to `'a'`, `w` is write mode, which overwrite existing file, while `a` is append mode

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me, but write now my whole file content appended. Can you tell me how I can append a particular portion of that file?

Comment: not quite understand your comment, if you want me to help further, could you include the more complete code page